# How to setup a Google Cloud load balancer to allow pointing domains with cname records?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, load-balancing, cdn, cname

I have recently started exploring the Google Cloud Platform **Cloud Load Balancer** and **Cloud CDN** products.

I am interested in setting up a load balancer to accept requests from multiple customer-pointed domains and map to an internal service.

Currently, I am creating multiple front-ends for the load balancer which feature a single domain and one or more SSL certificates. This creates a new ephemeral IP address per front-end that customer domains can be pointed to via `A` records.

**Instead, I would like to allow customers to point their domains to my service using `CNAME` records.**

eg. `demo.customerdomain.com` -> `CNAME` `service.mydomain.com`.

Can anyone help me figure out the best way to do this?

I am not sure what benefits/risks this has in terms of security or caching, so if anyone has any input on that, I would be interested to hear it.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try using a CNAME mapped to an A record? You must configure custom domain names at the load balancer frontend in addition to your DNS server. For HTTPS this is mandatory otherwise an untrusted site error will be displayed in the browser.

Comment: Yes, very helpful. I was not aware that I could simply do this from the DNS level on the 2nd domain.

Comment: Now to programmatically generate the front-end certs for the load balancer....

Comment: `request = service.sslCertificates().insert(project=project, body=ssl_certificate_body)` The terraform documentation is helpful in figuring out the API: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_managed_ssl_certificate REST API: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates